# Upsource: Merge reviews don't show anything in Review summary

Tags: git, merge, jetbrains-ide, review, upsource

I have Upsource running on a private server on my own in a Docker container. It is linked to a Github repo.

The settings are very basic, just a few files extensions are ignored, because it's a Unity Project (no need to review .meta files for instance).

When creating a merge review, the review summary doesn't show anything. If I create a branch review instead, on the same branch, it shows the changes instantly and correctly in the review summary.

When syncing PRs from Github, it can sometimes display the diffs in the review summary, but it takes 10 to 15 minutes to load, which makes it unusable.

Is this something that already happened to someone ? Is there a way to fix this, or is this an issue with Upsource ? I didn't see anyone mention this issue anywhere :/

Thanks for the help !